# How to export/import local groups with domain user members from/to a Windows server

Tags: windows, export, import, security-groups

What is the recommended way of cloning local group memberships (local groups, domain users) from one Windows server to another (script, tool, utility)? Servers are at version 2008 and later. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, since there appears to be no available solution, I built my own: https://github.com/alekdavis/CloneLocalGroups